# Unidentified index but the code is successfully functioning in PHP/AJAX/JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, dropdown

Basically I have **three dynamic dropdowns**

> The first one shows the categories
>
> The second one displays the sub category under the category that I
>   chose on the first dropdown
>
> The third one displays the topics under the sub category that I chose
>   on the second dropdown. This file is called testdropdown.php

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","imetrics");
?>
<form name="form1" action="" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Select Category</td>
            <td>
                <select id="categorydd" onChange="change_category()">
                    <option>--None Selected--</option>
                    <?php
                        $query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT category_id, categoryname FROM category WHERE ParentCategoryID IS NULL");
                        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row["category_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["categoryname"]; ?></option>
                    <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
             </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Select Subcategory</td>
             <td>
                <div id="subcategory">
                    <select>
                        <option>-- None Selected--</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
             </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Select Topic</td>
             <td>
                <div id="topic">
                   <select>
                      <option>-- None Selected--</option>
                   </select>
                </div>
             </td>
         </tr>
     </table>
 </form>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function change_category() {
       var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
       xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.php?category="+document.getElementById("categorydd").value,false);
       xmlhttp.send(null);
       document.getElementById("subcategory").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
       if(document.getElementById("categorydd").value=="--None Selected--") {
          document.getElementById("topic").innerHTML="<select><option>--None Selected--</option></select>";
       }
    }
    function change_subcategory() {
       var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
       xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.php?subcategory="+document.getElementById("subcategorydd").value,false);
       xmlhttp.send(null);
       document.getElementById("topic").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
 </script>
```

**ajax.php**

```
  <?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","imetrics");

    $category=$_GET["category"];
    $subcat=$_GET["subcategory"];

    if($category!="") {
        $query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT category_id, categoryname FROM category WHERE ParentCategoryID =$category ");
    echo "<select id='subcategorydd' onChange='change_subcategory()'>";
        echo " <option>--None Selected--</option>";
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo "<option value='$row[category_id]' selected>"; echo $row["categoryname"]; echo "</option>";
    }
        echo "</select>";
    }

    if($subcat!="") {
        $query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM topic WHERE SubCat = $subcat ");
        echo "<select>";
        echo " <option>--None Selected--</option>";
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            echo "<option value='$row[topic_id]' selected>"; echo $row["title"]; echo "</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
    }
 ?>
```

After clicking data from

> First dropdown it pops up this error Notice: Undefined index:
>   subcategory in **C:\xampp\htdocs\new\ajax.php on line 5**.

Then after clicking data from

> Second dropdown it pops up this error Notice: Undefined index:
>   category in **C:\xampp\htdocs\new\ajax.php on line 4.**

**That's the first weird thing.**

[image]

The **second weird** thing is the **function** `change_subcategory()` in **testdropdown.php.** I think that means it can't find the function but the code is working fine.

Comment: The syntax highlighting in your screenshot simply indicates that your IDE cannot find any uses of that function. This doesn't necessarily mean that there aren't any in reality

Comment: Try changing line in ajax.php to 
$category= isset($_GET["category"])?$_GET["category"]:"" ; 
$subcat=isset($_GET["subcategory"])?$_GET["subcategory"]:"";

Comment: Noted and thank you sir @Phil

Comment: thank you sir @Parag it worked! The errors are gone now.